# Characteristic of ring completions

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, completion

This may be a completely trivial question, but I haven’t seen it stated in any of the references I checked. Is the characteristic of a ring $R$ equal to that of its [completions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_of_a_ring)? This is true for the rationals, for example, by [Ostrowski‘s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%27s_theorem) but I don’t see how to show it holds in general.

Comment: The link about completions refers to many kind of completions, and it's not obvious whether there is one given precise meaning of completion to make the question clear-cut. Do you have a single example of "completion" of a ring that is not injective?

Comment: Very well. By a ring completion here I mean the projective limit of the quotient rings $\lim_{\leftarrow n}R/I^n$ for any proper ideal. I do not have a non-injective example and my question was whether one ever exists.

Comment: Yes, it exists. Take $R=R_1\times R_2$ where $R_1$ has characteristic $0$ and $R_2$ has characteristic $n>0$, and $I=R_1\times\{0\}$. (Note that this definition of "completion" doesn't encompass the rationals, the example you mentioned.)

Comment: It can also happen that $I=I^2$, in which case the completion is $R/I$.

Comment: However, it is true that the $m$-adic completion $\hat{R}$ of a Noetherian local ring $R$ with maximal ideal $m$ has the same characteristic as $R$.  It shares a lot of other properties with $R$ too.  Indeed, the map $R \rightarrow \hat{R}$ is faithfully flat with trivial closed fiber.